# how to use the result of impute.mean function in R?

Tags: r, mean, na

I have a dataset of 1302 sample in which I create MCAR NAs by deleting 5 percent of training part. then I try to impute this 5 percent with the mean of the other 95%. I just don't know how to access the result produced by the impute.mean function of the [HotDeckImputation Package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/HotDeckImputation/HotDeckImputation.pdf).

In the package manual guide, it says the result is in the form of matrix, anybody can tell me how to define a matrix to record the result? Also according to the package, the matrix should have the same size as the input of function(DATA).

you can see my code below:

```
NAValues = imptrainFolds[sample(nrow(trainFolds), 5),i]
imptrainFolds[NAValues,i] = NA

if(impType == "mean"){
 #calculate the mean for the remaining samples
 ? = impute.mean(DATA = as.matrix(imptrainFolds[[i]]))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Broadly speaking, if your intention is to replace the missing values in the data using means, you can use the code below:

```
#  Simulate data
N <- 10000
x1 <- rbinom(N,1,prob=.4)  
x2 <- rnorm(N,0,1)
dta <- data.frame(x1, x2)
dta$x2[dta$x1 == 1] <- NA

# Replace missing data
for (i in which(sapply(dta, is.numeric))) {
    dta[is.na(dta[, i]), i] <- mean(dta[, i],  na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

The few things worth considering are:

1. This is not a sophisticated method, packages like `Amelia II` offer more comprehensive way of handling the missing data
2. It is good to keep a flag for the data that was replaced, in the code above this is `dta$x1 == 1` but you may consider making it more explicit by adding another column

Comment: I will try to change my code to this one. the reason I used hotdeck package is that it has knn imputation as well so this would keep the integration of whole code.I like the idea of keeping a flag for NA, it might come in handy later.